# How to aligning content with css

Tags: html, css

I'm not able to align some images to the center using css. 
Here's the overall content of my page:

```
<body>
  <header>...</header>
  <div id="topBar">...</div>
  <div class="freeSpace">...</div>
</body>
```

inside "freeSpace" I just have an unordered list with the following content (written in php):

```
 echo('<li><div class="container">');
 echo('<div class="text-block">');
 echo("<p>Name: $name</p>");
 echo("<p>Cost: $nightCost € per night</p>");
 echo("<p>Address: $address</p>");
 echo("<p>Brief Description: $brief</p>");
 echo('</div>');
 echo("<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/blah\">");
 echo "<img class=\"houseImg\" src='data:$imgID;base64, $imgData' />";
 echo("</a>");
 echo('</div> </li>');
```

This is the current look of my page (ignore the placeholder 'booking.com' icon)

[image: current page look]

I want each container to be centered and I've used 'text-align: center' in various places, but it's just not working.

Here's the current CSS that is being applied to everything, but that isn't the header and 'topBar':

```
.freeSpace
{
    text-align: center;
}


.container {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 7em;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
    position: relative;
    width: 58em;
}

 .container>*>img:hover
{
    width: calc(100% + 3em);
}

.container>a , .container>*>img {
    transition: width 1s;
    width:inherit;
}

.text-block {
    text-align: center;
    transition: width 1s, top 1s;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 89.4%;
    height: 22.1%;
    margin: 4em;
    top: 25.2em;
    left: 3em;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 51;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your relevant CSS?

Comment: You can use <center></center> I suppose.

Comment: @MUFAzmi nop, this is obsolete for almost 20 years , maybe you like also the marquee and blink tag ?

Comment: *Ah, `<marquee>`* @G-Cyr :-))

Comment: here is some official ressource you may relay on and ask about if it fails : https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've got some wild stuff going on with your CSS, especially the `text-block` class.
Ignoring that, your main problem is the width on your `container` class.

Remove `width: 58em;` from `.container`

```css
.freeSpace
{
    text-align: center;
}


.container {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 7em;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
    position: relative;
}

 .container>*>img:hover
{
    width: calc(100% + 3em);
}

.container>a , .container>*>img {
    transition: width 1s;
    width:inherit;
}

.text-block {
    text-align: center;
    transition: width 1s, top 1s;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 89.4%;
    height: 22.1%;
    margin: 4em;
    top: 25.2em;
    left: 3em;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 51;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>...</header>
<div id="topBar">...</div>
<div class="freeSpace">
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>Name: $name</p>
        <p>Cost: $nightCost € per night</p>
        <p>Address: $address</p>
        <p>Brief Description: $brief</p>
      </div>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/blah">
        <img class="houseImg" src="data:$imgID;base64, $imgData" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```